# AWS cli skip files that are in use?

Tags: bash, amazon-s3

How does the AWS cli tool handle files that are in use?

My log files are created hourly (log-2018.01.26.13, 14, 15 etc). I was thinking of making a very simple aws cli mv script to move files to a S3 bucket and having that run every 10 minutes through cron to make sure I get logs as soon as possible.

However there will be files that haven't finished writing yet. Is the AWS cli smart enough to leave those files alone or do I need extra logic that first check whether files are in use?